# Spacy V3.5 Throws: Pipeline component 'set_tag_component' returned <class '__main__.SetTagComponent'> instead of a Doc

Tags: python, sql, nlp, tokenize, spacy-3

I have a Python code that looks like shown below.

I want to add tokenize my code and I want to tokenize SQL statements by keywords. For this, a custom component is created. The component is SetTagComponent but when I want to create the doc object via doc = nlp(sql) it throws me the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...Folder/nlp_skeleton.py/sql_statement_tokenizer_test.py", line 59, in 
doc = nlp(sql)
File "...Folderminiconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 1018, in **call**
raise ValueError(Errors.E005.format(name=name, returned_type=type(doc)))
ValueError: [E005] Pipeline component 'set_tag_component' returned <class '**main**.SetTagComponent'> instead of a Doc. If you're using a custom component, maybe you forgot to return the processed Doc?

I am confused because I assume that it returns the doc object in the **call** function but obviously this is not the case.

Can someone help me to spot why it states that I am returning <class'**main**.SetTagComponent'> instead of the processed doc object. Thank you!

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.language import Language

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Define custom part-of-speech tags
SQL_SELECT = "SQL_SELECT"
SQL_FROM = "SQL_FROM"
SQL_WHERE = "SQL_WHERE"
SQL_AND = "SQL_AND"
SQL_OR = "SQL_OR"

# Define SetTagComponent class to set custom tags for specific SQL keywords
@Language.component("set_tag_component")
class SetTagComponent:
    def __init__(self, nlp):
        Doc.set_extension("is_select", default=False, force=True)
        Doc.set_extension("is_from", default=False, force=True)
        Doc.set_extension("is_where", default=False, force=True)
        Doc.set_extension("is_and", default=False, force=True)
        Doc.set_extension("is_or", default=False, force=True)
        
    def __call__(self, doc):
        for token in doc:
            if token.text.lower() == "select":
                token._.is_select = True
                token.tag_ = SQL_SELECT
            elif token.text.lower() == "from":
                token._.is_from = True
                token.tag_ = SQL_FROM
            elif token.text.lower() == "where":
                token._.is_where = True
                token.tag_ = SQL_WHERE
            elif token.text.lower() == "and":
                token._.is_and = True
                token.tag_ = SQL_AND
            elif token.text.lower() == "or":
                token._.is_or = True
                token.tag_ = SQL_OR
        return doc

# Add SetTagComponent to spaCy pipeline
nlp.add_pipe("set_tag_component", last=True)

# Path to the text file containing SQL statements
file_path = "sql_select_statements.txt"

# Read SQL statements from text file
with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    sql_statements = f.readlines()

# Count of SELECT and FROM keywords
select_count = 0
from_count = 0

# Tokenize each SQL statement and count the number of SELECT and FROM keywords
for sql in sql_statements:
    doc = nlp(sql)
    for token in doc:
        if token._.get("is_select"):
            select_count += 1
        elif token._.get("is_from"):
            from_count += 1

# Print counts of SELECT and FROM keywords
print("Number of SELECT keywords:", select_count)
print("Number of FROM keywords:", from_count)
```

I checked the example in the spacy documentation here: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components and it seems to be correct. I searched on Github and Google of course but I was not lucky to find a good hint.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, if I run: print(nlp.pipeline) then I can see the following:

[('tok2vec', <spacy.pipeline.tok2vec.Tok2Vec object at 0x7fd5f1abfb20>), ('tagger', ..., ('set_tag_component', <class '__main__.SetTagComponent'>)].